# Using GNU Make to compile MathLink program automatically removes a file

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, raspberry-pi

*It's possible that this question belongs on Stackoverflow; however, the Mathematica context may be important so I'm asking here first.*

I am working on a project to interact with sensors connected to a Raspberry Pi via Mathematica.  The first version of the code is [here](https://github.com/bobthechemist/VernierPi) for reference and because of its simplicity, can be compiled with something like:

```
mcc -o vernier vernier.c vernier.tm -I/usr/include/GoIO -lGoIO
```

As the project becomes a bit more sophisticated, I decided to implement make.  Following the [Development guide](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WSTPDeveloperGuide-Unix.html#19046) and adding some tweaks I've learned along the way, I have this Makefile;

```
SHELL=/bin/bash # for access to shell expansion
CC = gcc
# Setting Wolfram directories
MVER = 10.3
MLINKDIR = /opt/Wolfram/WolframEngine/$(MVER)/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit
CADDSDIR = $(MLINKDIR)/Linux-ARM/CompilerAdditions
LIBDIR = $(CADDSDIR)
MPREP = $(CADDSDIR)/mprep
# Flags
CFLAGS = -I/usr/include/GoIO -I$(CADDSDIR)
LIBS = -lGoIO -lm -luuid -lML32i4
# Assume all .h files are dependencies
DEPS = $(shell ls *.h)
__OBJ = $(shell ls *.{c,tm})
_OBJ = $(__OBJ:.c=.o)
OBJ = $(_OBJ:.tm=tm.o)

vernier: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -L$(LIBDIR) $(LIBS) -o $@

$(ODIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPs)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

%tm.c : %.tm
    $(MPREP) $? -o $@

# For testing purposes, type `make print-VAR` to get the value of VAR
print-%: ; @echo $* = $($*)
```

The "nifty" part is searching for template files created with the extension (.tm) and running them through `mprep` to generate .c files.  What surprises me is that if I have this Makefile in the same directory as the aforementioned code (which contains a single vernier.c file with corresponding vernier.tm template), I get a successful compile **but the verniertm.c file generated by mprep is deleted at the end**!  I do not object, since it is a temporary file anyway; however my question is, *what causes this behavior?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a feature of `make`, see the manual for [Chains of Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html#Chained-Rules).

> Intermediate files are remade using their rules just like all other
>   files. But intermediate files are treated differently in two ways.
>
> The first difference is what happens if the intermediate file does not exist. If an ordinary file b does not exist, and make considers a target that depends on b, it invariably creates b and then updates the target from b. But if b is an intermediate file, then make can leave well enough alone. It won’t bother updating b, or the ultimate target, unless some prerequisite of b is newer than that target or there is some other reason to update that target.
>
> The second difference is that if make does create b in order to update
>   something else, it deletes b later on after it is no longer needed.
>   Therefore, an intermediate file which did not exist before make also
>   does not exist after make. make reports the deletion to you by
>   printing a ‘rm -f’ command showing which file it is deleting.

For preventing deletion of intermediate files, see the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Targets.html#Special-Targets) of the `.PRECIOUS` or `.SECONDARY` special targets (the second one might be specific to GNU make).

Comment: That's good enough for a necromancer badge :-)